# Dual Monitor Support in Kali Linux

Tags: drivers, kali-linux, nvidia, multi-monitor

I have a native install of Kali Linux on my custom PC which has an Intel Core i5 4690K CPU and an NVIDIA GTX960 GPU. The monitor plugged into my DVI port is working but my 2nd monitor plugged into HDMI is not. In fact, Kali is not even detecting the second monitor. I've tried to follow [Blackmore Ops' guide](http://www.blackmoreops.com/2015/02/12/kali-linux-1-1-0-kernel-3-18-install-proprietary-nvidia-driver/2/) to install the NVIDIA drivers figuring I need the proprietary drivers. However when I call `nvidia-xconfig` to generate the new config files and reboot, I get trapped on a black screen with a cursor and the only way to get out is to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> to recovery mode and remove the conf file. I've been grinding at this for hours and am hopelessly stuck.

There is a suggestion on page four of the guide to simply remove nouveau to get it to work. I tried it as specified with `apt-get remove -purge nouveau` but I get the output

```
E: Command line option 'p' [from -purge] is not known.
```

and when I try without `-purge` I get

```
E: Command line option 'p' [from -purge] is not known.
```

But I know it's there because when I issue `lsmod | grep nouveau` I get output.

As I said, I feel hopelessly stuck.

Comment: Purge is an action not a flag. `apt-get purge package`

Comment: It can be used as an option too, but with two hyphens: `apt-get --purge remove nouveau`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. I went to NVIDIA's website and downloaded their Linux drivers. It was a pain figuring out how to install them because of an x server error but it turns out I had to kill gdm3. Once I did that they installed and now it works.